# Arithmetic progressions and removal lemmas for graphs in arithmetic combinatorics

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, graph-theory, additive-combinatorics, hypergraph

As it is well known, one can gets a proof of Roth's Theorem concerning arithmetic progressions of length 3 (APs for short) by using the celebrated Ruzsa-Szemerédi triangle removal lemma for graphs.

In the Fourier analytic approach to Szemerédi's Theorem there is an important obstruction when trying to mimic Roth's proof to arithmetic progressions of length 4 (and, of course, in general for longer APs). This can be resumed in the Gowers quadratic 'counter-example', which tells that one needs to develop further technology to attack the problem.

My question is the following: to deal with 4-AP (to say the first problematic case) using the graph setting one needs to use hypergraphs (and all the machinery developed to get removal lemmas for hypergraphs). So, is there a purely 'graph theoretical obstruction' as in Gower's Fourier example which makes impossible a purely graph theoretical proof of Szemer'edi's Theorem?

Comment: I seem to recall that the challenge in the graph theoretic approach is simply finding a natural graph theoretic statement that implies the existence of 4-term APs in dense sets.  As alluded to in your post, there are natural Fourier analytic statements that imply the existence of 4-term APs but Gowers's examples show that their proofs require a larger family of "structured" functions than is necessary for Roth's theorem.  But I may be misremembering, or misinterpreting your question.

Comment: yes, this is exactly my question: which obstruction in graphs arise that makes that you need to deal with hypergraphs. In Fourier analysis is related to "quadratic Fourier analysis", I do not know if some analogue appears in graphs